# Solving a non-linear, improper integral equation

Tags: improper-integrals, nonlinear-system, integral-equations

I'm struggling with solving the following equation for $\Delta(\omega)$,
$$
\Delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\Omega}{\sqrt{\Omega^2+\Delta^2(\Omega)}}\left(\frac{\omega\Delta(\Omega)-\Omega\Delta(\omega)}{\omega}\right)\frac{1}{|\omega-\Omega|^{1/3}}
$$
the only information I have about $\Delta(\omega)$ is its value at $\omega=0$, $\Delta(0)=8.14$, I think I should be able to obtain some approximate solution by some iterative method, however I've no idea how to go about it for a equation of this form.

Comment: Are you sure the denominator of the second term is $\omega$ and not $\omega^2$? Because I think a cute trick is available if it is $\omega^2$.

Comment: Unfortunately it is $\omega$ :(, for reference the equation appears on this paper, it's equation $(18)$: http://magnet.fsu.edu/~bonestee/papers/prl96.pdf